# Why doesn't GRUB see my SSD partition?

Tags: linux, ssd, grub, grub2

I have a HP nc4400 laptop with an SSD drive in it.

Sometimes when I reboot I get a `There is no such partition. grub rescue >` prompt.

If I power cycle the laptop all is good and GRUB is able to find the first partition. 
This never happened while I had rotating HDD in the same laptop.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your Hard Drive is dying :( Try booting in with a live usb/cd/whatever and grab smarttools. You can start by running a short test on the drive which should take about 2 mins. However if that doesn't detect any issues you can try the longer tests. Most distros should have the smart tools package in repositories. The man page is fairly verbose so if you need a hand with it you can post here. Also it might be called smartmontools

Comment: I already have smartmontools installed. No issues detected. The first SSD indeed died within 3 months, this is its replacement, brand new one of course. I also ran many stress tests on the system. Again, no issues. But I experience random freezes, which may be related.

Comment: Yes - my SSD died. So far 2 in a row, both in about 3 months of occasional use. Well done, OCZ!